# Writing to DSE from an external Pig Job (Pig -> DSE connector)

Tags: cassandra, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I'm trying to write an EMR job running Pig that writes to DSE which we'll be using for serving. Unfortunately, I can't get Pig to write to DSE so I've broken down the problem to just connecting to the DSE node and try to write to it.
Here's what I'm doing

On Cassandra Node:

```
 cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE cql3ks WITH replication =
     {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };
 cqlsh> USE cql3ks
 cqlsh:cql3ks> CREATE TABLE test (a int PRIMARY KEY, b int);
```

From Local Machine

```
export PIG_INITIAL_ADDRESS=<cassandra node IP>
export PIG_RPC_PORT=9160
export PIG_PARTITIONER=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
pig -x local

grunt> REGISTER /var/lib/cassandra/resources/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.7.0.jar;
grunt> REGISTER /var/lib/cassandra/resources/cassandra/lib/cassandra-thrift-1.2.13.2.jar;
grunt> REGISTER /var/lib/cassandra/resources/cassandra/lib/cassandra-all-1.2.13.2.jar;
grunt> DEFINE CqlStorage org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CqlStorage();
grunt> moretestvalues= LOAD 'cql://cql3ks/test/' USING CqlStorage;
grunt> insertformat= FOREACH moretestvalues GENERATE TOTUPLE(TOTUPLE('a',a)),TOTUPLE(b);
grunt> STORE insertformat INTO 'cql://cql3ks/test?output_query=UPDATE+cql3ks.test+set+b+%3D+%3F' USING CqlStorage();
```

When I do this, I get the following errors:

```
2014-02-25 18:50:27,952 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2014-02-25 18:50:28,506 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
2014-02-25 18:50:28,506 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - There is no log file to write to.
2014-02-25 18:50:28,506 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.AbstractColumnFamilyOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(AbstractColumnFamilyOutputFormat.java:75)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:80)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator.validate(InputOutputFileValidator.java:45)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(HExecutionEngine.java:288)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.compilePp(PigServer.java:1322)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1247)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1239)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$400(PigServer.java:121)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1553)
at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of versions. You're probably using hadoop 2.x and Cassandra library is using hadoop 1.x api. If not check if you're using the correct jars.

Next Cassandra bugfix version (2.0.6) is going to include compatibility for both apis or at least this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5201) says so.